# Given a state $|\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+e^{i\theta}|1\rangle)$, how do I know the angle $\theta$?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, measurement, quantum-phase-estimation

**Question1.** If there is a state $|\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+e^{i\theta}|1\rangle)$, and I want to know the angle $\theta$. What kind of measurement should I do? Could somebody give me the quantum circuit?

**Question2.** How to perform a measurement with base $M{{({{\theta }_{k}})}_{\pm }}=\left\{ 1/\sqrt{2}\left( |0\rangle \pm {{e}^{-i{{\theta }_{k}}}}|1\rangle  \right) \right\}$ on IBMQ?

Comment: Do you have many copies of the state $|\phi\rangle$, or just one? Can you access them all at once, or do you have them just one at a time?

Comment: @WilliamYang in my answer for $\phi$ I assumed that we have many copies of the state $\phi$ (we can prepare them as many as we want). I will add this to my answer.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan but you also assumed you just get them one at a time. If you have them all at the same time, you can get a square root improvement I believe.

Comment: @DaftWullie yes, you are right, I assume also that I have them one at a time. Interesting! Can you, please, share some info/links about how this improvement is achieved?

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan I’ll write it up as a (partial) answer when I get the time. Basically, it’s the Fourier transform.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan hmmm maybe it doesn't quite work being given just the state $|\phi\rangle$ as compared to having an oracle that applies the unknown phase. I thought I'd seen something like it before, but cannot instantly reconstruct anything that out-performs your answer.

Comment: please do not ask more than one question per post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer to the first question**:

As mentioned in the comments of the question I assume that we can prepare $|\phi \rangle$ as many as we want. Let's calculate the relative phase for this one qubit *pure state*:

$$|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |0\rangle + e^{i\theta}|1\rangle\right)$$

We are going to execute $2$ different experiments in order to estimate $\theta$. In the first experiment we apply this circuit:

```
circuit_experiment_1.h(q[0])
circuit_experiment_1.measure(q[0], c[0])
```

The state after Hadamard gate:

$$H \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |0\rangle + e^{i\theta}|1\rangle\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1 + e^{i\theta})| 0 \rangle + (1 - e^{i\theta})| 1 \rangle \right]$$

The probabilities of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states:

\begin{align*}
P(0) = \frac{1}{4}\left| 1 + e^{i\theta} \right|^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(\theta))
\\
P(1) = \frac{1}{4}\left| 1 - e^{i\theta} \right|^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos(\theta))
\end{align*}

From here we can see that:

$$\theta = \pm \arccos\big(P(0) - P(1)\big)$$

because the range of usual principal value arccosine function is equal to $[0, \pi]$. So we will need the second experiment in order to estimate the $sign(\theta)$. But, before that, how to find $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ with the described experiment? We will need to execute the circuit $N$ times (bigger $N$ gives better precision) and take into accout these relations between measurement outcomes and probabilities:

\begin{align*}
P(0) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{N_{0}}{N}
\qquad
P(1) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{N_{1}}{N}
\end{align*}

where $N_{0}$ is the number of $|0\rangle$ measurement outcomes and $N_{1}$ is the number of $|1\rangle$ measurement outcomes. Also, note that:

$$\langle X \rangle = \langle \psi | X | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi |H Z H| \psi \rangle = P(0) - P(1)$$

So, the formula can be written in this way:

$$\theta = \pm \arccos \big( \langle X \rangle \big)$$

**The sign of the $\theta$**

Now we should determine the $sign(\theta)$ with this circuit:

```
circuit_experiment_2.sdg(q[0])
circuit_experiment_2.h(q[0])
circuit_experiment_2.measure(q[0], c[0])
```

The state after applying $S^{\dagger}$ and $H$ gates:

$$H S^{\dagger} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |0\rangle + e^{i\theta}|1\rangle\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1 - i e^{i\theta})| 0 \rangle + (1 + i e^{i\theta})| 1 \rangle \right]$$

with the same logic:

\begin{align*}
P'(0) = \frac{1}{4}\left| 1 - ie^{i\theta} \right|^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \sin(\theta))
\\
P'(1) = \frac{1}{4}\left| 1 + ie^{i\theta} \right|^2 = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \sin(\theta))
\end{align*}

So after determining the $P'(0)$ and $P'(1)$ from the second experiment we will find the sign of the $\theta$:

$$sign(\theta) = sign(\arcsin\left(P'(0) -  P'(1)\right)) = sign(P'(0) -  P'(1))$$

because the range of usual principal value of arcsine function is $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Also, note that for the expectation value of the $Y$ operator (as can be seen from this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11789/9459)) we have this relation:

$$\langle Y \rangle = \langle \psi| Y | \psi\rangle = \langle \psi| S H Z H S^{\dagger} | \psi\rangle = P'(0) -  P'(1)$$

By taking this into account and combining two results:

\begin{align*}
\theta =  sign \big(\langle Y \rangle \big) \arccos \big(\langle X \rangle \big)
\end{align*}

An approach for finding the relative phase of an arbitrary *pure state* is described in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13055/9459).

**Answer to the second question**:

Here is the circuit for measuring in $M{{({{\theta }_{k}})}_{\pm }}=\left\{ 1/\sqrt{2}\left( |0\rangle \pm {{e}^{-i{{\theta }_{k}}}}|1\rangle  \right) \right\}$ basis. I assume here that $\theta_k$ is given:

```
circuit.u1(theta_k, q[0])    # q[0] is one of the qubits
circuit.h(q[0])
circuit.measure(q[0], c[0])   #c[0] is a classical bit
```

If the state was $M(\theta _k)_+= 1/\sqrt{2}\left( |0\rangle + e^{-i\theta _k}|1\rangle  \right)$, then the outcome of the circuit will be $|0\rangle$, and if it was $M(\theta _k)_-= 1/\sqrt{2}\left( |0\rangle - e^{-i\theta _k}|1\rangle  \right)$, then the outcome of the circuit will be $|1\rangle$. So this way we will be able to measure in $M{{({{\theta }_{k}})}_{\pm }}$ basis.

Comment: Thank you so much! You do help me a lot!

Comment: Nice answer. Just one question, why not to calculate an angle as $\theta = \arccos(2P(|0\rangle)-1)$ or $\theta = \arccos(1-2P(|1\rangle))$? I supposed you subtracted probabilities $P(|0\rangle)$ and $P(|1\rangle)$ from each other, right?

Comment: Thanks Martin. You are right. I will add also that expression to the equation in the answer. I think $P(0) - P(1)$ is a more easily understandable expression, so I will keep it :)

Comment: @WilliamYang, I did a mistake, it is corrected now. In the previous version of the answer, I didn't calculate $\theta$, there was a sign ambiguity that comes from the arccosine function that I haven't taken into account.

Comment: Sorry,but what if I have only one state $|\varphi\rangle$ at a time?What kind of measurement should I do to get $\theta$?

Comment: @WilliamYang, if we don't have the possibility to recreate the state $|\varphi \rangle$ as many times as we want and if we don't have any information about $\theta$, then I don't know a method that will find the $\theta$ :). But if we have information about $\theta$ like in the second question, then it is possible to find out if we have $+\theta$ or $-\theta$ with one measurement as is shown in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would just like to share a code for testing a phase measurement on IBM Q:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[1];
creg c[1];

//measuring theta in
//(|0> + |1>*exp(i*theta))

h q[0]; //(|0> + |1>)
t q[0]; //(|0> + |1>*exp(i*pi/4))
//s q[0]; //(|0> + |1>*exp(i*pi/2))
//u1 (pi/8) q[0]; //(|0> + |1>*exp(i*pi/8))

h q[0]; //measurment in Hadamard basis

measure q[0] -> c[0];
```

*Tested on IBM Q Armonk (1 qubit processor).*

---

**EDIT** (*based on Davit comment*):
To infer a sign of the phase, a measurement in circular basis (i.e. adding $S^\dagger$ gate before Hadamard gate) has to be done as well. Combining results from measurement in Hadamard basis and circular basis gives complete knowledge about the phase.

Comment: Thank you Martin ：）

Comment: Martin, actually I realized that I had a mistake in my calculations in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11355/9459). There was a sign ambiguity that comes from the arccosine function that I haven't taken into account. I have corrected my answer. So, if I am right, then the circuit mentioned in this answer doesn't calculate the desired relative phase.

Comment: With a slight adjustment, the circuit will work. We can prepare the same state on two qubits and apply two different experiments described in the [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11355/9459) at the same time (or separately on a single qubit).

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan: I think that the circuit work correcly but only for phases between $0$ and $\pi$ as these values are returned by arccos.

Comment: yes they work correctly for that values, but not for the relative phases between $\pi$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan: Hi, I edited my answer. Just one question. I think we can replace $S$ with $S^\dagger$, right? Only one difference will be a sign before $i$ and switching formulas for $P'(0)$ and $P'(1)$.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes we can replace $S$ with $S^{\dagger}$ and I think it is a good suggestion because in that case $P'(0) - P'(1) = \langle Y \rangle$ (as can be seen from this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11789/9459)). Thanks, I will edit the answers accordingly (changing $S$ to $S^\dagger$).

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan: Thanks. So, in the end to have a complete knowledge of the state, we need to do measurement in three bases - computational (z), Hadamard (x) and circular (y). Effectivelly, we did state tomography.

Comment: Martin, yes we did QST. BTW I was trying to avoid that :). Nevertheless, if for each expectation value we need to run let say $1000$ experiments for the precision, then the overall number of experiments will be $N = 3000$, but I think with this technique for the same precision $2000 < N \le 3000$ experiments will be needed. When the phase is near to $0$ we can execute QST, otherwise, we will do fewer experiments in order to estimate only the sign of the phase.

Comment: Actually, there are some points (caveats) that should be proved to claim that this actually gives an advantage. One caveat is that $\langle Y \rangle$ gives not only info about the sign of the phase but also about the phase (with arcsine function) and I guess it might improve the precision of the estimated phase.