# How to get the relative phase of an entangled pair of qubits

Tags: quantum-algorithms, entanglement, quantum-phase-estimation

I have an extension to the following question: [How to get the relative phase of a qubit?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/how-to-get-the-relative-phase-of-a-qubit)
How do I get the relative phase of a pair of entangled qubits such as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+e^{i\theta}|11\rangle)$$

in which I want to find theta. I tried to use a similar methodology as the answer in the linked question above, but with no success.

Comment: In the thread that was mentioned in the question, there was a mistake in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11355/9459), that is corrected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Apply a CNOT gate with one of the qubits as control and the other as target. You'll get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+e^{i\theta}|1\rangle) \otimes |0\rangle$$

2. Use the methodology from [How to get the relative phase of a qubit?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/how-to-get-the-relative-phase-of-a-qubit) for the first qubit :-)

Comment: Hmm I tried that in the simulator but for some reason it didn't work. Then most likely its just a silly-mistake type issue with the way I wrote it. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be the state after CNOT $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{i\theta}|1\rangle)\otimes |0\rangle$?

Comment: @MartinVesely Fixed, thank you - a typical off-by-one error :-)