# Can I see Probability in complex form after measuring the state of the qubit on quantum computer?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-state

> Let's say I have a qubit
> $$\left| \psi \right> = (\alpha_1 + i\alpha_2 ) \left|0\right> + (\beta_1 + i\beta_2 )\left|1\right>$$

so when we measure it will calculate $|\alpha_1 + i\alpha_2|^2$ and $|\beta_1 + i\beta_2|^2$ ,and it will give the state with highest probability.

```
enter preformatted text here

vector = [159+625j,3+71j]  

print(vector)
norm = np.linalg.norm(vector)
print(norm)
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)  # Create a quantum circuit with one qubit
initial_state = vector/np.linalg.norm(vector)
print('initial state is')
print(initial_state)
qc.initialize(initial_state, 0) 
qc.x(0) ###### for not gate
qc.h(0) ####### for hadamard gate
a = qc.draw() 
print(a)

simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator') 
qobj = assemble(qc)     # Create a Qobj from the circuit for the simulator to run
result = simulator.run(qobj).result() # Do the simulation and return the result
out_state = result.get_statevector()
print(out_state)
```

Now the code to run on Quantum computer is

```
enter preformatted text here
IBMQ.load_account()
#provider = IBMQ.get_provider = ('ibm-q')
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
qcomp= provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
job = execute(qc,backend=qcomp)
from qiskit.tools.monitor import  job_monitor
job_monitor(job)
result = job.result()
plot_histogram(result.get_counts(qc))
```

when we run this on Quantum computer we will get a graph with probabilities on it are those probabilities calculated using $|\alpha_1 + i\alpha_2|^2$ and $|\beta_1 + i\beta_2|^2$ these formulas?
is it possible to extract in the form of a complex number like $a+ib$ not just like 0.865 or something like that, can I see what are my $\alpha$'s and  $\beta$ 's after measuring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it possible to guess what state the qubit was in by measuring it?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13051/how-is-it-possible-to-guess-what-state-the-qubit-was-in-by-measuring-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use state vector simulator on IBM Q to get amplitudes but this is simulation.

In practise, you have to use quantum tomography to get the state vector. In short, the tomography allows you to look at a quantum state from *different angles* which actually means to measure copies of the state in different basis. See more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography).

To do so for one qubit, the link provided by *KAJ226* is the most useful way how to do so easily.