# In quantum teleportation, Is it possible for bob to just see the state vector after receiving it from Alice without measuring it?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, teleportation

I was reading about quantum teleportation using Qiskit. Alice wants to teleport some quantum state to Bob. My question is **Is it possible for bob just to see the state vector after receiving it from Alice without measuring it?**

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. The state vector describes a distribution of a possible outcomes after measurement the quantum state. So, to reconstruct the state vector, the measurement has to be performed.

If you can assume that the amplitudes in the state vector are real numbers only, you can only repeat the measurement several times in the computational basis to get reasonable statistics.

However, when a quantum phase is involved (i.e. the amplitudes are complex), you have to measure in other bases (e.g. Hadamard)as well or do complete [tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography) to reconstruct the state vector.

Note that in Qiskit you can employ `statevector_simulator` which reveals the state vector, however, as the name suggest, it only a simulation on a classical computer. In quatum world, the measurement (even repeated one) is necessary to get the state vector.

Comment: Thank you for responding, So if my amplitudes are complex numbers then I can use tomography to reconstruct back the complex amplitudes after I measured it? Is that correct? Or did I understand it wrong.

Comment: Yes, for general state. For one qubit it is possible to use a method proposed here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/given-a-state-phi-rangle-frac1-sqrt20-rangleei-theta1-rangle/11356#11356 However, the measurement cannot be avoided.

Comment: So by that I will teleport the quantum state for Alice to Bob and at Bobs  side I have to do tomography to look into state of qubit  .

Comment: @bhagiradh: Yes, by teleportation you only move the qubits from Alice to Bob. To get whole state vector on Bob side, generally you need to do tomography (with exception to special cases I meant before).

Comment: There is no 'moving' of qubits involved in teleportation. Moreover, it should be noted you need _many copies _ of a state to perform state tomography - you cannot determine the full state of a single qubit.

Comment: @JSdJ: Thank  you for the comment. I know that we need many copies to do the tomography, however, it is only possible way how to get whole state vector. Concerning the moving qubits, I meant the qubits which are teleported, sorry for imprecise expression.